# Applying a filter to an `Ext.data.Store` while adding to said store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have some JavaScript which presents my user with a list of items. They can choose to filter the items (there are lot to see) and at the same time, server pushes are adding new items.

When the user chooses a filter, I'm applying a filter to an `Ext.data.Store` like so:

```
myStore.filterBy(function(record) {
    return (record.data.type === filter);
});
```

When the server pushes a new items to display, I'm using `addSorted` to add it:

```
myStore.addSorted(new Ext.data.Record.create(fields)(item));
```

... but when the user chooses a filter, new items sent by the server aren't getting filtered out.

How can I set up an `Ext.data.Store` filter such that calls to `addSorted` and `add` will respect the filter being applied to the store?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only solution is to re-apply the filterBy function after adding the new record.